# Windows 8 secondary tile pin

Tags: windows, windows-8

We implemented the code as in [the msdn sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Secondary-Tiles-Sample-edf2a178#content). But the navigation from secondary tile not works well. i.e, Assume we pinned from a page "A", and then navigated to another page "B", while clicking on secondary tile, it navigates to the Page "B". This is an issue, or should we specify navigation arguments anywhere while creating the tile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the secondary tile you define the tileActivationArguments

```
string tileActivationArguments = "Page=3";
```

and when creating creating the the secondary tile you give tileActionvationArguments as a parameter. Then when someone starts your application from the secondary tile you need to catch the tileActivationArguments.

```
MainPage rootPage = MainPage.Current;
if (MainPage.Current.LaunchArgs != null) 
{ 
   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(MainPage.Current.LaunchArgs.Arguments)) 
   {
      //Get information from arguments where to navigate
   }
}
```